# How to find summation formula for the following power series?

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, summation-method

How to find  $\text{summation formula}$  for the following power series?

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{((an+b)!)^{an+b}}{r+((an+b)!)^{an+b}} p_k(n) \cdot \frac{x^n}{(an+b)!} , \ r \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}, \ a \in \mathbb{N}, \ b \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0 \},$$ where $p_k(n)$ is some polynomial in $n$ of degree $k$.

The above power series converges everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$.

I need to find general summation formula. But, how to find this?

My purpose is to show when the sum becomes a rational number by finding the summation formula.

One thing seems to me that using some recurrence relation we can drive the summation formula.

**Can someone give me some hints to derive the summation formula?**

Comment: You are missing a bracket in the denominator, can you add one so that the summation makes sense?

Comment: @PeterForeman, I have edited my question

Comment: Why do you think there should be a closed form for this series?

Comment: @GregMartin, I am not asking the exact sum, but I need the summation formula based on the polynomial $p_k(n)$ for different particular cases. I need just the summation formula to show that the sum of the series can be a rational number. Can you give some hintz ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the summation formula", if not a closed form?

Comment: @GregMartin, off course in closed form